# How to test cases with intervals in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with the value in A1 = 94. I would like to put in B1 a calculation such as:

```
if A1 is within [85;90], then B1 = A
else if A1 is within [90;95], then B1 = B 
else if A1 is within [95;100], then B1 = C
```

is there a way to do it quickly without VBA please?

Comment: What if A1 is 90 or 95? Or below 85 or higher than 100?

Comment: That is not the point @JvdV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested `IF`s

Paste this formula in B1:

```
=IF(A1>=85, IF(A1>=90, IF(A1>=95, IF(A1>100, "Too High", "C"), "B"), "A"), "Too Low")
```

If A1 = 85, 90 or 95 it will round up a category not down - to change that replace `>=` with `>` in the formula

Comment: Strictly this doesn't do exactly as the OP asked, it's more like "If A1 is more than 100 then too high, else if A1 is more than 95 then C, else ... "